# How can I make this generate 0.00 and 100?

Tags: php

I need to cryptographically generate a number between 0.00 and 100.00.

I came up with this:

```
$number = round(random_int(0, 10000)/ 100, 2);
```

It works very well, however, it is not generating the number 100.00 or 0.00. How can I modify this so it does that? It only seems to be generating numbers from 0.01 to 99.99.

Comment: Odd, the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) says `random_int`'s min and max parameters are inclusive.

Comment: How do you know that your code will never generate 0.00 or 100.00, as opposed to those numbers just randomly not having been generated yet? What kind of tests did you run?

Comment: I am guessing you are expecting to see the decimals when they will not be there for 0 or 100

Answer (score 0):

Are you outputting the number as a string? If so you sometimes get rounding errors like this. Use number_format instead of round

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it *does* generate 0 and 100.

I generated 100,000 numbers, and it generated `0` 11 times and `100` 12 times.

Results here: https://ideone.com/73mz58